# Setting CurrentUICulture for program started in automated tests

Tags: c#, localization, automated-tests

I am currently looking to setting the CurrentUICulture for automated (graybox) UI-tests of a C# (WPF) application. The UI-testing is performed with SpecFlow for the test-cases and FlaUI for UI-automation within the steps. Hence this is not about how I can set the `CurrentUICulture` from within the application, but from the outside.

Unfortunately the state of my research led me to the point to assume, that it's bleakly impossible to set the UI culture of a C# application I'm starting, but I hoped for a faint chance, that someone knows some way to achieve this.

I've read some answers here that state that we could set the `CurrentUICulture` in a PowerShell console and the language (or locale) would be propagated to things started from this PowerShell session, but this seems to hold true for cmdlets only, not for applications started from that PowerShell session, which arguably makes sense. I confirmed that this holds true for applications started with `Process.Start`, from another application the `CurrentUICulture` has been set for. Since `FlaUI` seems to use `Process.Start`, too (FlaUIs `Application.Launch` takes a `ProcessStartInfo`, object which lets me think that it uses `Process.Start`, but I have not confirmed this), I assume that the behavior will be the same. Furthermore there is no possibility to pass a locale to `Process.Start` directly.

I even tried setting `Thread.CurrentUICulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` in the program that is calling the program to test, but to no avail neither.

I know that setting the Windows UI language globally requires a restart for the changes to become effective, which rules this out for automated testing. Even setting up another user and running the program as this user does not seem to help. The culture settings (`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`) for that user are passed to the software, but the language (`CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`) is not.

The `CurrentCulture` can be set within the session and I *could* use this to determine which language to use, but this feels like a hack I would like to avoid. Is there any other way to set the language for the program to run?

Comment: Is it "your" WPF Application? Why not introduce a command line parameter for overriding the culture? Can be handy in many ways

Comment: @Klamsi Of course we could introduce a workaround for testing, but we would not test how our Application is called in the real world, which would render our tests pretty much useless (our localization by itself is proven, but choosing the language based on `CurrentUICulture` is new and hence to be tested)

Comment: Hmm. As you cannot have an operating system with all cultures at once you will never be able to test "the real world". If you set your "Current Culture" dependent of an existing parameter I think you are quite safe. What can go wrong?